# How to display HTML output from PHP return function

Tags: php, html

I have the function `displayName` in php that returns a string like this:

```
"${name} <i class=\"fa fa-check-circle\" style=\"font-size:22px;color:green\"/>"
```

```
public function getDisplayName()
{
    /** @var Module $module */
    $module = Yii::$app->getModule('user');

    if ($module->displayNameCallback !== null) {
        return call_user_func($module->displayNameCallback, $this);
    }

    $name = '';

    $format = Yii::$app->settings->get('displayNameFormat');

    if ($this->profile !== null && $format == '{profile.firstname} {profile.lastname}') {
        $name = $this->profile->firstname . ' ' . $this->profile->lastname;          
        if (($this->profile->user_id == 1)){
            $check_mark = '<i class="fa fa-check-circle" style="font-size:22px;color:green"/>';
        }
        else{
            $check_mark = '';   
        }
    }

    // Return always username as fallback
    if ($name == '' || $name == ' ') {
        return $this->username;
    }

    return $name . ' '.  $check_mark;
}
```

I call that function in my component like this:

```
public function run() {
  return $this->render('containerProfileHeader', [ 'title' => $this->title, ]);
}
    
<h1 class="<?= $classPrefix ?>"><?= Html::encode($title) ?></h1>
    
public function init() {
  parent::init();
  $this->title = $this->container->getDisplayName();
}
```

The expectation was having the string returned by `getDisplayName()` rendered in the html as is but instead I've got this:

[image: Output Screenshot]

Comment: The question is unclear. I better indented your code in the meanwhile. Anyway it seems like you have a function returning `Name <i [...]/>` but you want it returned `<i [...]/> Name`?

Comment: @DiegoD I want to show output of the HTML code, The HTML code is visible after name, I want to show output of the HTML Code.

For example

Now I got output John <i class="fa fa-check-circle" style="font-size:22px;color:green"/>

Comment: @DiegoD The output I got:
[Output Screenshot][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JComL.png

Comment: ok finally it's clear. The problem is that string is being escaped by your template system. Where do you call your function getDisplayName()? there's the key on how to tell to echo the string as raw with no escaping

Comment: @DiegoD
    public function run()
    {
        return $this->render('containerProfileHeader', [
            'title' => $this->title,
           
        ]);
    }
 <h1 class="<?= $classPrefix ?>"><?= Html::encode($title) ?></h1>

Comment: @DiegoD
 public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->title = $this->container->getDisplayName();
      
    }

Comment: @DiegoD
And the html code in inspect is

<a href="#" data-contentcontainer-id="1" data-guid="1a261c8c-8b41-4932-ae24-d10f1fe6fded">Noman Maken&lt;i class="fa fa-check-circle" style="font-size:22px;color:green"/&gt;</a>

Comment: I think the problem is you are using `Html::encode($title)`. I'm not familiary with yii (it looks like that), but can you try to echo the string as is avoiding the processing made by HTML::encode? is that possible?

Comment: @DiegoD got this in view source  ```<h1>Noman Maken &lt;i class=&quot;fa fa-check-circle&quot; style=&quot;font-size:22px;color:green&quot;/&gt;</h1>```, I think if I can replace with &lt with < and other from javascript then it may be work, I have tried this but not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved from

```
<?= Yii::$app->formatter->asHtml($title); ?>
```

Used

`Yii::$app->formatter->asHtml` instead of `Html::encode`

Answer (score -2):

You should try echo() functions in the return function. I hope it will work.

Comment: This should be a comment. Also a function should never be responsible for outputting content